# How to setup Internet on Windows XP Hyper-V VM?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, internet, hyper-v

I have everything almost done: I have properly setup Legacy Network Adapter on the VM; I was able to have network in the XP VM (see image below). But I am not able to access the Internet, see Internet Explorer window below.

Any directions?

- Firewall in the XP is disabled by the way.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Are you *sure* you don't have network connectivity? Trying to load page in IE 6 is NOT a proper way to test. How do you have networking configured in Hyper-V?

Comment: you are right, internet was working all along. I install IE 8 and I could browse around. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh install of Windows XP will install Internet Explorer 6. This browser is so old that you'll find it difficult to find a website it can actually load. Instead you'll get the *Page cannot be displayed* error, suggesting that you don't have network connectivity.

A better way to confirm Internet connectivity is to ping an IP address on the public Internet such as `8.8.8.8`.

You can also install a newer browser and try loading the web page from it.